# Align Icons in Tab Layout To The Left

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Hello I have created a tab layout in my activity.  This is the main **.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxx.eventmanager.EventDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorLight"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textAlignment=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my **.java** class:

```
package com.xxxxxx.eventmanager;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.xxxxxx.eventmanager.adapters.EventPagerAdapter;

public class EventDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     *
     * private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
     *
     */

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Details").setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_details));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sales").setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_sales));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Purchases").setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_purchase));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final EventPagerAdapter adapter = new EventPagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_event_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Now currently the tab displays like this:
[image]

However now I would like the icons to display on the left hand side of the text instead of on top of the text.

Answer (score 6):

I have exact solution which you guys want.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:tabInlineLabel="true"
    app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/default_10dp">
```

Using below property you can achive desire result.

app:tabInlineLabel="true"

Answer (score 3):

Just add this line to your TabLayout in XML

```
app:tabInlineLabel="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Tjerkw is ok just that it doesn't loop through the entire tab. I guess the right solution should be this

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++ ) {
     yourlinearlayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.title_text, null);
     tab_text = (TextView) yourlinearlayout.findViewById(R.id.tabContent);
            tab_text.setText("  " + tab_titles[i]);
     tab_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(tabicons[i], 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tab_text);}
```

and the layout resource .xml representing `R.layout.title_text` will be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

finally, the `tabicons[i]` and tab `tab_titles[i]` are just String arrays containing their respective contents.
 I know this question's old but i recently faced this and i'm sure someone else might still need this

Answer (score 1):

TabLayout also support custom views instead of TabView.

**1.Create your tab item layout**.The main idea is we should use specify id
 for ImageView **@android:id/icon** and for TextView **@android:id/text1**

**R.layout.custom_tab_item**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_app_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/appoinments_" />

    <com.app.barber.views.CustomTextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:text="@string/title_appointments"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2. And TabLayout xml file**

> ```
>  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>       android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>       app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
>       app:tabGravity="fill"
>       app:tabMode="fixed"
>       android:theme="@style/vocabularyTheme.ActionBar" />
> ```

**3. Create tabLayout using custom views, and remove bottom margin, which was set up by default 8dp**

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);     
mTabLayout.addTab(createTab(text1,icon1));
mTabLayout.addTab(createTab(text2,icon2));

private TabLayout.Tab createTab(String text, Drawable icon){
    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.newTab().setText(text).setIcon(icon).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab_item);

    // remove imageView bottom margin
    if (tab.getCustomView() != null){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams());
        lp.bottomMargin = 0;
        imageView.requestLayout();
    }

    return tab;
}
```

***Expected result.***

[image: Align Icons in Tab Layout To The Left]

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom view:

```
TextView newTab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
newTab.setText("tab1"); //tab label txt
newTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(your_drawable_icon_here, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(tab_index_here_).setCustomView(newTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce `ActionMenuView` inside `Toolbar`.

From [Google Official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ActionMenuView.html) ***"ActionMenuView is a presentation of a series of menu options as a View. It provides several top level options as action buttons while spilling remaining options over as items in an overflow menu. This allows applications to present packs of actions inline with specific or repeating content."***

Eg,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And on your Activity,

```
Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tToolbar);
    amvMenu = (ActionMenuView) t.findViewById(R.id.amvMenu);
    amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
      }
    });
```