# How to make tab title alignment to left in TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I can't seem to align my tab titles to the left, inside my TabLayout. At the moment, the titles are centered. Here is what [I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy6FP.jpg) to achieve.

And this is what [I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYcHP.png) at the moment.
The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/slate_grey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding one more tab without any title and disable it. I don't know if it will work but i think you can give it a try.

Comment: @SripadRaj That's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Try defining `tabGravity="start"` and `tabMode="scrollable`.

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160978/align-icons-in-tab-layout-to-the-left/46247521#46247521

Answer (score 33):

add `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to your `<TabLayout.../>` and don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` too.

For more info check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: This should be correct answer. Also can be done by code,    `tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE)`

Answer (score 7):

Just set the TabLayout width to wrap_content. Done.

Comment: this seems to break the text into 2 lines when one is longer than others.

Answer (score 1):

Try **app:tabPaddingEnd=""** very late answer but hope it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

There is a way out ....
wrap your Tablayout with a Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
           android:layout_width="169dp"
           android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
           app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
           app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
           app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
           app:tabPaddingEnd="-3dp"
           app:tabPaddingStart="-6dp"
           app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
           app:tabTextColor="#717171" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Elvis' answer, the `app:tabPadding*` attributes could help you to distribute (or normalize the length of) the tab titles.